# Solium and GeoPandas for Regional Analysis

Tags: python, geopandas, folium

Based on my previous question : [pandas  and melting of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76301579/convert-multi-column-table-into-two-column)

here is  again full code and output :

```
import pandas as pd
data =pd.read_excel("https://geostat.ge/media/52189/visits-by-visited-region.xlsx",skiprows=[0])
# data.dropna(axis=0,inplace=True)
data.drop(["Year","Quarter","Total","Other regions"],axis=1,inplace=True)
data["Country"] ="Georgia"
data.columns.name = 'Regions'
data = pd.melt(data, value_name='Visitors').assign(Country='Georgia')
data = data[data["Regions"].str.contains("Country") == False]
data.dropna(axis=0,inplace=True)
data =data.groupby(["Regions","Country"])['Visitors'].sum().reset_index()
# data.columns =["Regions","Country","Total_Visitors"]
# data["Country"] ="Georgia"
print(data.head())
```

result is :

```
         Regions  Country     Visitors
0         Adjara A/R  Georgia  4885.150598
1            Imereti  Georgia  7453.780645
2            Kakheti  Georgia  3288.265509
3       Kvemo Kartli  Georgia  2920.524336
4  Mtskheta-Mtianeti  Georgia  2765.860204
```

now i decided to use folium and geopandas for displaying result on Map, here is my current code :

```
import pandas as pd
import folium
import geopandas
data =pd.read_excel("https://geostat.ge/media/52189/visits-by-visited-region.xlsx",skiprows=[0])
# data.dropna(axis=0,inplace=True)
data.drop(["Year","Quarter","Total","Other regions"],axis=1,inplace=True)
data["Country"] ="Georgia"
data.columns.name = 'Regions'
data = pd.melt(data, value_name='Visitors').assign(Country='Georgia')
data = data[data["Regions"].str.contains("Country") == False]
data.dropna(axis=0,inplace=True)
data =data.groupby(["Regions","Country"])['Visitors'].sum().reset_index()
world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
table= world.merge(data ,how="left", left_on=['name'], right_on=['Country'])
table.dropna(axis=0,inplace=True)
# print(table.head())
earth =folium.Map()

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=table,
    name='choropleth',
    data=table,
    columns=['Regions','Visitors'],
    key_on='feature.properties.name',
    fill_color='OrRd',
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Visitors per Region'
).add_to(earth)
earth.save('visitors.html')
```

here is screenshot of visitors.html
[image: Georgia]

i am not sure whether this result is correct or not -yes it is Georgia(Sakartvelo), but i want its regions, am i missing something?i was thing about getting coordinates or Latitude position and  Longitude position ?actually for instance Kakheti [Kakheti region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakheti)

covers  large area and  maybe because of this it shows  such black  surface on georgia? i will try to select some  regions  and also please  give me your recomendations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your approach, you need a [*dataset*](https://github.com/wmgeolab/geoBoundaries/blob/main/releaseData/gbOpen/GEO/ADM1/geoBoundaries-GEO-ADM1_simplified.geojson) that hold the geographic info of Georgia's regions :

```
url = "https://github.com/wmgeolab/geoBoundaries/raw/905b0ba/" \
      "releaseData/gbOpen/GEO/ADM1/geoBoundaries-GEO-ADM1_simplified.geojson"

pgs = gpd.read_file(url)
pgs["shapeName"] = pgs["shapeName"].replace(
                              {"Adjara": "Adjara A/R", "–": "-"}, regex=True)

out = pgs.merge(data, left_on="shapeName", right_on="Regions")

m = folium.Map(location=[pgs.centroid.y.mean(), pgs.centroid.x.mean()], zoom_start=7)

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=out,
    name="choropleth",
    data=merged,
    columns=["Regions", "Visitors"],
    key_on="properties.shapeName",
    fill_color="RdGy",
    fill_opacity=0.8,
    line_opacity=0.8,
    legend_name="Visitors",
).add_to(m)

m.save("visitors.html")
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: i can't beleive  that you have done  -my dear friend if you visit georgia i will invite you to kakheti for  red  wine taste  . thanks bro