# Folium map warning

Tags: python, geopandas, folium

Based on previuos question [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76301982/solium-and-geopandas-for-regional-analysis)

i have implemented following code :

```
import pandas as pd
import folium
import geopandas as gpd
import geopandas
data =pd.read_excel("https://geostat.ge/media/48824/13_Earnings-by-regions_annual.xlsx",skiprows=[0,1])
data.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0':"Regions"},inplace=True)
data.dropna(axis=0,inplace=True)
data.drop(index=0,inplace=True)
data["Total"] =data.sum(axis=1,numeric_only=True)
data =data[["Regions","Total"]]
data["Country"] ="Georgia"
print(data.head())
url = "https://github.com/wmgeolab/geoBoundaries/raw/905b0ba/" \
      "releaseData/gbOpen/GEO/ADM1/geoBoundaries-GEO-ADM1_simplified.geojson"

pgs = gpd.read_file(url)
pgs["shapeName"] = pgs["shapeName"].replace(
                              {"Adjara": "Adjara A.R.", "–": "-"}, regex=True)

out = pgs.merge(data, left_on="shapeName", right_on="Regions")
# df1.to_crs('+proj=cea').centroid.to_crs(df1.crs)
m = folium.Map(location=[pgs.centroid.y.mean(), pgs.centroid.x.mean()], zoom_start=7)

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=out,
    name="choropleth",
    data=data,
    columns=["Regions", "Total"],
    key_on="properties.shapeName",
    fill_color="RdGy",
    fill_opacity=0.8,
    line_opacity=0.8,
    legend_name="Spent Money",
).add_to(m)

m.save("Money_Spent.html")
```

but it gave me warning :

```
UserWarning: Geometry is in a geographic CRS. Results from 'centroid' are likely incorrect. Use 'GeoSeries.to_crs()' to re-project geometries to a projected CRS before this operation.

  m = folium.Map(location=[pgs.centroid.y.mean(), pgs.centroid.x.mean()], zoom_start=7)
```

i have searched and found this link :
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372564/userwarning-when-trying-to-get-centroid-from-a-polygon-geopandas

but did not get exactly how can i apply it to my code? please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a warning and in your case, it's not really a big issue because the [`centroid`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.centroid.html) is used in your code to just find a pair of coordinates that will let us center the map (*to point right above the center of Georgia*). So, even if the calculations wouldn't be precise enough, the map will got centered due to the small surfaces of the polygons/regions (as explained by @Louis Cotterreau [*here*](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/372568/197233)).

But if you nevertheless want to get rid of the warning, you can use this :

```
#pip install pyproj
from pyproj import Transformer

transformer = Transformer.from_crs("EPSG:32638", "EPSG:4326", always_xy=True)

x, y = [pgs.to_crs(32638).centroid.x.mean(), pgs.to_crs(32638).centroid.y.mean()]

lon, lat = transformer.transform(x, y)

m = folium.Map(location=(lat, lon), zoom_start=7)
```